# sha256 of locally built docker image

Tags: docker, sha256, docker-image

How do I get the sha256 checksum of an already locally built docker image?

I want to use the checksum to annotate a `FROM` instruction in a derived image:

```
FROM name@sha256:checksum
```

I already tried checksums from `docker inspect`.

- Neither the first nor the last of the checksums in the `Layers` list worked.
- The one in `"Id"` did not work.
- The one in `"Parent"` did not work.
- The one in `"Container"` did not work.
- The one in `"Image"` did not work.

Some of them I only tried out of desperation to finally find the correct checksum for my docker image, but I cannot find the correct checksum. Only thing I did not try yet, because of the number of layers, is to go through *all* of the layers in case they are in a random order. But to put them there like that would not make sense to begin with.

The error I see when I run `docker build -t <some name> .` in the directory of the Dockerfile of the derived image when it is not working is:

```
Step 1/7 : FROM name@sha256:<checksum> repository name not found: does not exist or no pull access
```

## Info

- Docker version: `Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be` (obtained via `docker --version`)
- Output of `docker info`:

  ```
  Containers: 0
   Running: 0
   Paused: 0
   Stopped: 0
  Images: 3841
  Server Version: 17.05.0-ce
  Storage Driver: aufs
   Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
   Backing Filesystem: extfs
   Dirs: 2620
   Dirperm1 Supported: true
  Logging Driver: json-file
  Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
  Plugins: 
   Volume: local
   Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
  Swarm: inactive
  Runtimes: runc
  Default Runtime: runc
  Init Binary: docker-init
  containerd version: 9048e5e50717ea4497b757314bad98ea3763c145
  runc version: 9c2d8d184e5da67c95d601382adf14862e4f2228
  init version: 949e6fa
  Security Options:
   apparmor
   seccomp
    Profile: default
  Kernel Version: 4.4.0-78-generic
  Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
  OSType: linux
  Architecture: x86_64
  CPUs: 4
  Total Memory: 7.684GiB
  Name: xiaolong-hp-pavilion
  ID: QCJS:JPK4:KC7J:6MYF:WWCA:XQM2:7AF7:HWWI:BRZK:GT6B:D2NP:OJFS
  Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
  Debug Mode (client): false
  Debug Mode (server): false
  Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
  Experimental: false
  Insecure Registries:
   127.0.0.0/8
  Live Restore Enabled: false

  WARNING: No swap limit support
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The checksum docker is looking for in the `FROM` line comes from the registry server. In the inspect output, you'll see this in the RepoDigest section:

```
docker inspect -f '{{.RepoDigests}}' $image_name
```

If you haven't pushed this image to a registry server, then you won't be able to use this hash value.

E.g.:

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{.RepoDigests}}' busybox:latest
[busybox@sha256:32f093055929dbc23dec4d03e09dfe971f5973a9ca5cf059cbfb644c206aa83f]

$ cat df.testsha
FROM busybox@sha256:32f093055929dbc23dec4d03e09dfe971f5973a9ca5cf059cbfb644c206aa83f
CMD echo "hello world"

$ docker build -f df.testsha -t test-sha .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  23.35MB
Step 1/2 : FROM busybox@sha256:32f093055929dbc23dec4d03e09dfe971f5973a9ca5cf059cbfb644c206aa83f
 ---> 00f017a8c2a6
Step 2/2 : CMD echo "hello world"
 ---> Running in c516e5b6a694
 ---> 68dc47866183
Removing intermediate container c516e5b6a694
Successfully built 68dc47866183
Successfully tagged test-sha:latest

$ docker run --rm test-sha
hello world
```

Comment: I don't understand why would anyone exclude such possibility. Is there an alternative way to ensure that I am deriving from the correct image?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. The purpose is to allow images to be reliably built on different hosts and know they have the same image. The docker way to move images between hosts is to use a registry. Docker Hub is one registry, or you can run your own private registry using the registry docker image (available on the hub).

Comment: I guess I'll simply accept this answer. I seem to have come from a wrong assumption (that I could use sha256 checksum for locally built, non registry images).