# How to verify locally built docker images?

Tags: docker, checksum, sha256, docker-image

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44087012/1829329) it turned out, that I cannot use the `sha256` mechanism in the `FROM` line in a `Dockerfile` to verify I am using the correct locally built non-DockerHub image in another derived image.

Is there another way to verify locally built Docker images? Some best practice maybe?

Comment: docker docs do not mention anything about it, so I think BMitch's comment on that question you mentioned is the only answer possible at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/#pull-from-a-different-registry):

> By default, docker pull pulls images from Docker Hub. It is also
>   possible to manually specify the path of a registry to pull from

You can start a [private docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/) on you localhost with the following command:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

Say your image name is`ubuntu` Then push image to that specific registry with:

```
docker push localhost:5000/ubuntu
```

In your Dockerfile you can use:

```
From localhost:5000/ubuntu
```